# JS/JQuery: Как добавить значения в двумерный массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div id="calendar">
<div class="control-date">01.12</div> 
<div class="control-date">03.12</div> 
<div class="control-date">04.12</div>
<div class="control-date">07.12</div>
```

Как с помощью JS или Jquery сделать из этого двумерный массив, чтобы результат
был вот такой:

```
var holidays = [
    [1,12],
    [3,12],
    [4,12],
    [7,12]
];
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
const holidays = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#calendar > div.control-date'),
  div => div.innerText.split('.').map(Number)
);

console.log(holidays);
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
<div class="control-date">01.12</div> 
<div class="control-date">03.12</div> 
<div class="control-date">04.12</div>
<div class="control-date">07.12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!